# adding annotations for each facet in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to add some annotations for each facet in ggplot. Previous posts suggest creating a new data frame of annotations. So I created a data frame accordingly. But somehow, the code did not work and gave me error message saying that prev_variant is not found. However, the code did work before “p+ geom_text”. Can someone help me out the let me know what might be the right way to do this? Thanks!

Here is the code I have now and the graph I want to make:

```r
plot_pred <- ggplot(pred.data.same, aes(Same_meaning_copy, pred, fill=Prev_variant)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge" ) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#1b9e77",  "#d95f02"),
                    labels = c("-tou", "-mian")) +
  ylim(c(0,1))+
  theme(text=element_text(family = "STKaiti")) +
  theme(text=element_text(size=12)) +
  ylab("Predicted -mian rate") +
  xlab("Same meaning")

plot_pred

labels <- c("no" = "Interspeaker", "yes" = "Intraspeaker")
 
p <- plot_pred +
  guides(fill = guide_legend(title = "Prime variant")) +
  facet_grid(.~Same_speaker,
             labeller = labeller(Same_speaker = labels)) +
  annotate("text", x = 1, y= 0.55, label = "ns") +
  geom_segment(aes(x = 0.85, y = 0.52 , xend = 1.15, yend = 0.52))

p

anno <- data.frame(x1 = c(1.85, 2.15),
                   x2 = c(1.85, 2.15),
                   y1 = c(0.72, 0.72),
                   y2 = c(0.82, 0.82),
                   xstar = c(1.85, 1.85),
                   ystar = c(0.75, 0.85),
                   labs = c("*", "***"),
                   dataset = c("Interspeaker", "Intraspeaker"))
 

p  + geom_text(data = anno, aes(x = xstar, y = ystar, label = labs)) +
     geom_segment(data = anno, aes (x = x1, xend = x1, y=y1, yend =y1))+
     geom_segment(data = anno, aes (x = x2, xend = x2, y=y2, yend =y2))
```

my desired output:

[image: my desired output]

Comment: Move the `fill=Prev_variant` aesthetics from the `ggplot()` "global" plot settings to the `geom_bar()` layer

Comment: @MrFlick Thanks. But still the two facets have the same annotation, whereas I would like to have unique annotations for each facet. :)

Comment: Since you are using `Same_speaker` as your faceting variable, the `anno` data frame should also have that variable with the same variables in order to tell ggplot which values go to which facet.

Comment: @MrFlick Yeah I get this and the dataset in the anno data frame is for this purpose ~but still it does not work. 
I get same annotations for both facets.

Comment: The variable has to match the one used in the facet command. You would need to have a column named `Same_speaker` that has values "yes" or "no". The data for each facet us subset by that variable. I do not believe there is a way to use different variable names for faceting on different layers.